# column matching of two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to match columns of 2 dataframes and getting the output as false. is there a way to find what is the **"not equal"** data?

code:

```
rounds2['company_permalink'].equals(companies['permalink'])
```

output:

```
  False
```

Comment: Please share minimal reproducible example [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

if i have understood the question:

```
data1 = {'col_1': [22, 34, 23, 43], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
data2 = {'col_1': [22, 66, 23, 88], 'col_2': ['x', 'b', 'c', 'y']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)


not_equal_col1 = df1['col_1']!=df2['col_1']
print(df1[not_equal_col1])
print(df2[not_equal_col1])
```

Output:

```
   col_1 col_2
1     34     b
3     43     d
   col_1 col_2
1     66     b
3     88     y
```